# ember.js template not rendered

Tags: ember.js

While it doesn't become simpler than this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfNJ8/1/)  I can't get the template to be rendered. I'm obviously missing something simple but have been starring at this for hours now. Can somebody spot the error?

When debugging in chrome I can see that the View is entered as well as the controller, but the template doesn't seem to come to life. I have several other ember tests running on my laptop that render just fine.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h1>Application</h1>

    <p>Your content here.</p>

    {{outlet}}

</script>

Albumartist = Ember.Application.create();

Albumartist.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
});

Albumartist.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
});

Albumartist.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});

Albumartist.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model){
        console.log('hi');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple: You chose Ember as a Framework didn't include jQuery, which is necessary for Ember to run. I've updated [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RfNJ8/2/) to include **Ember and Handlebars** as a **resource** and **jQuery** as a **Framework**.

Also, since Router v2.1 you don't have to pass the `match` argument to the router:

```
Albumartist.Router.map(function() { // no match argument needed anymore
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
});
```

Comment: thanks! now the fiddle works, it's still not working locally. Probably a dependancy issue. I'll sort it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you need to wrap your code in `<script>` tags which appear to be missing. This could possibly by a typo when copying your code over to this site though.

Comment: hi, it's running in a rails application and the individual files are served by Rails, that works well, I can see them all correctly in the debug console. Even the template is normally just a index.handlebars file, that I only included in a script tag for the fiddle. thanks for looking at it though.